# remove/replace octal escapes from html

Tags: ruby, octal

I have octal escapes in my html(stored as a string), which displays on the browser as �.

eg:- "Thanks for the update\205.nt"

Is there a way to remove these from the string or make it render properly on the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

blunt solution :

```
"Thanks for the update\205".encode('ascii', :invalid => :replace, :replace => "")
=>"Thanks for the update"
```

see [String#encode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html) for a more subtle approach

Answer (score 0):

.gsub(/[^[:print:]]/, ' ') works perfectly.

http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2010/10/remove-non-printable-characters-from-string-using-ruby-regex/